# How to apply a particular stylesheet class to a table when there are already "table,td,tr" selectors style specified in stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have CSS file in which I have the following styles already applied:-

```
table{...}  
table td{...}
```

It gets applied on all the tables. But I want to change the style of some particular tables. I created a new class and applied it to those tables. But the tables still get their styles from the above selectors, not from the class applied.

Comment: You're getting your wires crossed somewhere. A class selector will override a tag selector. [See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/YbMb2/).

Comment: Yes, problem solved, thanks, I was not applying style to .Class td but only to .Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some styles may not be inherited by a table's children when you select `table.yourclass` alone, whether the class selector is there or not.

You need to apply them to `table.yourclass tr`, `table.yourclass th` and/or `table.yourclass td`.